# How to produce these references using latex ( journal name : Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications)

Tags: latex

How to produce these references using latex ( journal name : Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications)
[1] S. Anita, Analysis and Control of Age-Depended Population Dynamics, Kluwer Academic Publishers, 2000.

[2]E. Barucci, F. Gozzi, Investment in a vintage capital model, Res. Econ. 52 (1998) 159–188.

[3]R. Boucekkine, N. Hritonenko, Y. Yatsenko (Eds.), Optimal Control of Age-Structured Populations in Economy, Demog-raphy, and the Environment, Routledge, 2013.

[4]M. Brokate, Pontryagin’s principle for control problems in age-dependent population dynamics, J. Math. Biol. 23 (1985) 75–101.

[5]A.V. Dmitruk, N.P. Osmolovskii, Necessary conditions for a weak minimum in optimal control problems with integral equations subject to state and mixed constraints, SIAM J. Control Optim. 52 (2014) 3437–3462.

[6]A.Ya. Dubobitskii, A.A. Milyutin, Necessary conditions for a weak extremum in general optimal control problem, Zh. Vychisl. Mat. Mat. Fiz. 8(4) (1968) 725–779 (in Russian).

[7]S. Faggian, Hamilton–Jacobi equations arising from boundary control problems with state constraints, SIAM J. Control Optim. 47(4) (2008) 2157–2178.

[8]G. Feichtinger, R.F. Hartl, P.M. Kort, V.M. Veliov, Anticipation effects of technological progress on capital accumulation: a vintage capital approach, J. Econom. Theory 126 (2006) 143–164.

[9]G. Feichtinger, R.F. Hartl, P.M. Kort, V.M. Veliov, Financially constrained capital investments: the effects of disembodied and embodied technological progress, J. Math. Econom. 44 (2008) 459–483.

[10]G. Fiechtinger, G. Tragler, V. Veliov, Optimality conditions for age-structured control systems, J. Math. Anal. Appl. 288 (2003) 47–68.

[11]G. Gripenberg, S.O. Londen, O. Staffans, Volterra Integral and Functional Equations, Cambridge Univ. Press, 1990.

[12]M. Iannelli, Mathematical Theory of Age-Structured Population Dynamics, Giardini Editori, Pisa, 1995.

[13]L.V. Kantorovich, G.P. Akilov, Funkcionalny Analiz (Functional Analysis), Nauka, Moscow, 1984 (in Russian).

[14]M.I. Krastanov, N.K. Ribarska, Ts.Y. Tsachev, Pontryagin maximum principle for infinite-dimensional problems, SIAM J. Control Optim. 49(5) (2011) 2155–2182.

[15]M. Kuhn, S. Wrzaczek, A. Prskawetz, G. Feichtinger, Optimal choice of health and retirement in a life-cycle model, J.Econom. Theory 158 (2015) 186–212.

[16]A.A. Milyutin, A.V. Dmitruk, N.P. Osmolovskii, Maximum Principle in Optimal Control, Moscow State University, Faculty of Mechanics and Mathematics, Moscow, 2004 (in Russian).

[17]C. Saglam, V.M. Veliov, Role of endogenous vintage specific depreciation on the optimal behavior of firms, Int. J. Econ. Theory 4(3) (2008) 381–410.

[18]V.M. Veliov, Optimal control of heterogeneous systems: basic theory, J. Math. Anal. Appl. 346 (2008) 227–242.

[19]G.F. Webb, Theory of Nonlinear Age-Dependent Population Dynamics, Marcel Dekker, 1985.

[20]M.L. Weitzman, Income, Wealth, and the Maximum Principle, Harvard University Press, 2003.

[21]K. Yosida, E. Hewitt, Finitely Additive Measures, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 72 (1952) 46–66.

Answer (score 0):

Your journal provides a class file [here](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions) with a template. I strongly suggest using the template if you have not already.

The first thing you need to do is create a separate .bib file for your bibliography. Open a new document with your editor and save it as `your-bib-database.bib` 
It will be called into the main document when you use `\bibliography{<your-bib-database>}` and un-comment the template code below it.

The references should look something like this-- I did a couple for you. You can reference more examples and the documentation [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex).

```
 @article{anita-key,
    author =       "S. Anita",
    title =        "{Analysis and Control of Age-Depended Population Dynamics}",
    journal =      "Kluwer Academic Publishers",
    year =         "2000",

}

@article{AVD-key,
    author =       "A.V. Dmitruk, N.P. Osmolovskii",
    title =        "{Necessary conditions for a weak minimum in optimal control problems with integral equations subject to state and mixed constraints}",
    journal =      "SIAM J. Control Optim.",
    volume =       "52",
    pages =        "3437–3462",
    year =         "2014",
}
```

According to the template, you will add each item in your document using from the .bib file using `\bibitem{key}`